# App is available for iPad in app store (unwanted)

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded my binary to the app store and in the project portion of the Xcode project it is set to "Devices iPhone". However in the app store it says:

Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch.

Why is my app available on iPad? I haven't designed this app for iPad and I don't want it to be available on iPad. What is the deal? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to tell Apple that an app is only for iPhone. All iPhone apps work on iPads.

What's more, if you make your app support iPad and iPhone specifically by changing the assets used based on the device, you can't tell which device it is being bought on.

For that information, you would have to make a seperate iPad-only app. But even then, people can buy the iPhone version for their iPad if they want.

Apps listed as only for iPhone run in a window which has the aspect ratio of an iPhone. The user can choose to run them at 2x magnification if they want it to take up more of the screen.

Comment: Oh, well will it appear as full screen or will it be a zoomed out version of the iPhone app

Comment: Edited answer to add info.

Answer (score 2):

iPad runs nearly all applications, or apps, designed for iPhone and iPod touch available in the App Store. The App Store also features many applications designed specifically for iPad.

Here are some things to remember when using apps designed for iPhone and iPod touch on your iPad:

1. Apps may only work in portrait or landscape orientation. These apps will change orientation even with screen rotation lock on.
2. Apps can run in their original size or expand to fill the screen. Tap the 1x or 2x icon in the bottom right of the screen to switch between sizes.
3. Text and graphics may not appear as sharp when using 2x mode. If you prefer sharper text and graphics, use 1x instead.
4. Some features may not be available on iPad (for example, apps that let you make phone calls or use the iPhone camera to take pictures).

More details: [Support-Apple:iPad: Using applications designed for iPhone and iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4082)